# jquery file uploader for multiple files with multiple progress bar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have got requirement to upload multiple video's and i need progress bar for each file upload.I'm using paperclip and query file up loader. I don't know where im doing wrong, i could able to upload multiple file but I'm not getting multiple progress bar.here is my code.please help me out guys.

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @course,:html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <% if @course.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@course.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this course from being saved:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @course.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :music %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :music %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>
    <div id="upload-file-container">
       <%= f.file_field :video, multiple:true, id: "fileupload", name: "course[video]"%>
    </div>
    <div id="progress">
       <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>``
    </div>
<% end %>


courses.js


jQuery(function() {

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        $('<p/>').text("Uploading ... "+file.name).appendTo(document.body);
    });
    data.submit();
},
done: function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        $('<p/>').text("Upload complete ..."+file.name).appendTo(document.body);
    });
},
change:function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        data.context = $('<p/>').text('Selected file: ' + file.name).appendTo(document.body);
    });
}  
}).on('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .bar').css('width',progress + '%').text(progress + '%'); 
    if (data.loaded == data.total) {
         $('#progress').hide();
        $('#progress .bar').css('width', '0%');
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Wow your code really needs indentation :) There are several queries I have -- You're sending the files over JSON. Are you sure this is sending them correctly? Secondly, have you followed [this tutorial](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) on how to do it?

Comment: Hello peck, Yes i'm sending through JSON. Yes exactly i have followed that [tutorial](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) only.@RichPeck

Answer (score 0):

You only have one div in your view for a progress bar. You should add multiple divs to your view dynamically as you need them, which you could do using jquery templating eg https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl.

If you were to use jquery-tmpl, it would look something like:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        $('<p/>').text("Uploading ... "+file.name).appendTo(document.body);
    });
    #=> file = data.files[0];
    #=> data.tmpl = $(tmpl("#my-template", file));
    #=> $("#some-div").append(data.tmpl);
    data.submit();
}


.on('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    #=> if (data.tmpl){
    #=>  data.tmpl.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
    #=>}
    if (data.loaded == data.total) {
         $('#progress').hide();
        $('#progress .bar').css('width', '0%');
    }
 });
```

view:

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/x-tmpl">
<div class="upload">
  <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
</div>
</script>
```

There is a great railscast on this topic, but you need a pro account.

Comment: Hello,is there any possibilities to do without using Template.I don't want to use template.